# Is there a way I can give the username and password as parameter in command line while running a jar

Tags: java, jar

I have a jar file which will let me connect to an instance. Once I run the command java -jar jarname in command line it will ask for username and password. Is there a way I can give the username and password as parameter in command line ?

Comment: I tries by proving the username and password but its still prompting for the same

Comment: Perhaps `java -jar bla.jar < credentials.txt` will do ? Put user and pass each on its own line. This is not very secure but might do the job if you can't modify the jar. If you can: show the source

Comment: giving error Username: Password: Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
        at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Unknown Source)

Comment: We have no idea what it is that you're running and how it asks for username and password, or what command line options or configurations it has. You should contact the company or person who wrote the software that you're running. In addition it doesn't seem like a programming question either (unless you're running a programming-related tool)

Answer (score 3):

Here are 3 options:

**Option 1**

If you want to read the arguments in main method, use :

```
 java -jar yourjar.jar user1 pass1
```

and then in your code:

```
public static void main(String [] args) {
     String user   = args[0]; // = user1 
     String passwd = args[1]; // = pass1  
}
```

**Option 2**

Alternatively if you want to pass system properties, then use `-D`:

```
java -jar -Duser=user1 -Dpasswd=pass1 yourjar.jar
```

And then in java:

```
String user   = System.getProperty("user"); // user1
String passwd = System.getProperty("pass"); // pass1
```

**Option 3**

You can also pass data via Environment Variables, but you should set them first in some script:

```
 set USER_NAME = "user1"
 set PASSWD    = "passwd1"
```

Then you run:

```
java -jar yourjar.jar // note, nothing is passed here
```

In java you can read the environment variables like this:

```
System.getenv("USER_NAME"); // user1
System.getenv("PASSWD");    // passwd1
```

Comment: I also have similar requirement where i have a java code (jar file) that will connect to another instance based on username and pass provided in the cmd line on execution, did the above solution worked for you?